# Need a regular expression "After $ symbol only I should accept particular strings give by me

Tags: java

I need a regular expression for the pattern. 
After `$` symbol I should only accept particular strings. For example: 
productNumber, productRevision

If none of the strings occur after `$` it should not be wrong.

Expected Result:

`$productNumber`, `$productRevision` should be right.

`$hello`, `$king` and ect.. should be wrong

Comment: It seems like you know what you are asking, but I can't tell. Could you try to be more specific with what you are trying to figure out? Maybe provide a snippet of code that shows what ideas you have tried?

Comment: why do you need regex? why not `String::contains("$" + expr)` where `expr` is in a list of valid strings?

Comment: What you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

For your example it will be like this:

^\$productNumber|\$productRevision$

You can do it in a loop:

"^" +

loop by words:

- if first: "\$" + expectedWord
- in not first: "|\$" + expectedWord

+ "$"